# Can I control the draw order in FX Composer?

Tags: render, shader, nvidia, cg

I'm using Nvidia FX Composer to write a semi-transparent CgFX shader.  Everything is fine, expect that in my render view, objects in the back of the scene are getting drawn on top of my shaded object.

here's my technique:

```
technique Main  {
    pass p0  
    {
        DepthTestEnable = true;
        DepthMask = false;
        CullFaceEnable = false;
        BlendEnable = true;
        BlendFunc = int2(SrcAlpha, OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        DepthFunc = LEqual;
        VertexProgram = compile vp40 std_VS();
        FragmentProgram = compile gp4fp std_PS();
    }
}
```

If I turn on DepthMask, then objects in the back get masked out entirely, which defeats the purpose of transparency.  It seems like the objects are not being drawn back-to-front.  Is there a way to confirm that, and can I control the order in which FX Composer's renderer draws items to the screen?

Comment: Without depth mask no the depth buffer technique doesn't work. Indeed it seems objects are not depth sorted before rendering. I don't know if this can be taught to FxComposer. But you can do this then in your program.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done inside a shader, you need to change the application using it. The general rule is to draw all solid objects first, and then all transparent objects over top.

Once you've drawn a transparent object, you can't render objects behind it and expect them to be blended. OpenGL can either render it, or not render it (due to z-buffer culling).

Drawing objects back to front is usually too expensive to do in real time, as it would require re-sorting *the whole scene* 60 times a second!

Comment: In this case, the application using the shader is FX Composer.  My question is whether FX Composer can be told to render scene objects (at least transparent ones) in order from back to front.